# adding list box elements using GUI builder in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, listbox, google-apps-script

I am new to javaScript so I need help using App Script.
In GUI Builder, I have added a list box by name "List Stocks" and in Events I have added a function "listStockQuotes()". I have no idea of how to add elements to this list box and display them. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is possible to add items to a listbox only by write code like in the following

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var form = app.loadComponent('gui00');
  var listBox1 = app.getElementById('ListBox1');
  listBox1.addItem('Item 00', 'Value00');
  listBox1.addItem('Item 01', 'Value01');
  listBox1.addItem('Item 01', 'Value02');
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}
```